# How to display compilation output of php code on browser

Tags: php, html, xampp

I need to compile the php code on HTML Button click and display the compilation output on browser.I am using the following code to display the output on browser,it works well in terminal but doesn't give anything on browser.I am using XAMPP server on windows machine.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['compile'])){
       $cmd="php php_part.php";
       $var=system($cmd);
       echo $var;
     }
?>

<input type="submit" class="button" name="compile" value="Compile Code"  />
```

Comment: PHP code doesn't get compiled unless you use `HHVM`.

Comment: What do you mean by "compilation output"? When I run `php filename.php` in the terminal, it just runs the script and displays whatever it prints, nothing about the compilation unless there are errors.

Comment: The return value of `system()` is just the last line of the output. If you want all the output, use `shell_exec()`.

Answer (score 0):

First you are not compiling the php_part.php script, you are running it. Yes I realise that running a php script requires that it first be compiled or rather **interpreted** but that statement will execute the php_part.php script.

There are 2 likely reasons why it is not running.

1. When run from the browser i.e via Apache it does not know where to find php.exe
2. Depending on where the php_part.php script is kept it may not be able to find that either.

Try changing this statement

```
$cmd="php php_part.php";
```

to

```
$cmd="C:/path/to/php/php.exe C:/path/to/script/php_part.php";
```

If that works then that above was the problem.

I have to also say that there must be a better way of running this script. As you are in a PHP section of code would not a simple `include` or `require` not be a better solution. Something like this

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['compile'])){
       require "php php_part.php";
       echo $var;
     }
?>
```

Of course this depend on how you have written that php_part.php script. If you wrote it as a function then this would be a better solution

The php_part.php script

```
function xxx() {
    // do whatever coding
    return $the_result;
}
```

The main code

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['compile'])){
       require "php php_part.php";
       $var = xxx();
     }
?>
```